# Does C++11 have an std::atomic<T>::add_and_fetch method?

Tags: c++, c++11

The C++11 standard includes the wonderful `std::atomic<T>`, which has member functions like this one:

```
integral fetch_add(integral, memory_order = memory_order_seq_cst);
```

However, it seems to be lacking in an `add_fetch` method.  `tbb::atomic<T>` overloads the `+=` operator to behave like `add_and_fetch`:

```
 value_type operator+=( D addend ) {
     return fetch_and_add(addend)+addend;
 }
```

Through empirical observation, `std::atomic<T>` behaves the same way, but I cannot find where it says so in the standard or if that is just my STL implementation.  Is this behavior guaranteed by the standard?

Comment: As an aside, for those using GCC that don't care about compatibility, there are builtins both __sync_fetch_and_add as well as __sync_add_and_fetch.  See GCC Manual Section 6.51 Built-in functions for atomic memory access.

Comment: Avoiding the GCC-specific builtins is exactly why I'm using `atomic<T>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::atomic<T>` if `T` is an integral type, has a member `operator+=` which does the same thing. It is described, along with all other atomic compound assignment operators in `§29.6.5/30-32`

> C A::operator op=(M operand) volatile noexcept;
>
> C A::operator op=(M operand) noexcept;
>
> Effects: fetch_key(operand)
>
> Returns: fetch_key(operand) op operand

Comment: So what constitutes an integral type? Which operators must I overload on T in order to have atomic<T>::fetch_or, atomic<T>::fetch_add methods?

Comment: @Eloff the usual integer primitive types except boolean: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30869374/895245 , no objects.

Answer (score 6):

You're right that it doesn't actually provide that functionality but that's because it isn't needed. It can be emulated with [the operations already there](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic).

`atomic_fetch_add` is an atomic operation that fetches the current value then adds something. That "something" is totally under your control and is not changed by `atomic_fetch_add`.

The standard guarantees that:

1. The old value is returned; and
2. The value is added.

You can then simply add the value yourself to what was returned, and you have the current value as of the time the atomic operation was done. So basically:

```
def atomic_add_fetch (item, addendum):
    return atomic_fetch_add (item, addendum) + addendum
```

is the pseudo-code for an `atomic_add_fetch` operation.

Answer (score 3):

> However, it seems to be lacking in an add_fetch method.

Why would it need one? `add_fetch` would be this:

```
return atomic_value.fetch_add(number) + number;
```

Yes, it technically requires an extra addition. But that's pretty minor.

In any case, there is no `add_fetch` in the standard. There's just `fetch_add`, which returns the original value.