# c++ std::atomic<bool>::fetch_or not implemented?

Tags: c++, embedded, atomic

With this excerpt of code:

```
class myclass {
    volatile std::atomic<bool> flag;
    public:
    myclass(): flag(false) {}
    bool get_flag() { return flag; }
    bool try_set() {
        return !flag.fetch_or(flag, true);
    }
    void reset() {
        flag = false;
    }
};
```

I am having this compile error:

```
error: ‘volatile struct std::atomic<bool>’ has no member named ‘fetch_or’   
   return !flag.fetch_or(flag, true);
```

It compiles if, however, I change the template parameter to `int`:

```
class myclass {
    volatile std::atomic<int> flag;
    public:
    myclass(): flag(0) {}
    bool get_flag() { return flag; }
    bool try_set() {
        return !flag.fetch_or(flag, true);
    }
    void reset() {
        flag = 0;
    }
};
```

The [atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) reference says that "the full specialization `atomic<bool>`" is treated as "non-specialized", what I believe to be the source of the problems. So my doubts:

1. How can a "full specialization" be "treated as non-specialized"?
2. May there I face any tricky pitfalls using as flag template parameter `int` instead of `bool` when calling `flag.fetch_or()`?

I am using gcc 5.1.0, and compiling with `-std=c++14`.

Comment: Have you looked into the [`fetch_or`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_or)? It's only defined for *Integral* data type.

Comment: Use `compare_exchange_strong`.

Comment: I don't understand: `atomic<int>::fetch_or()` cannot take `bool` as a second argument, only an optional `memory_order`.

Comment: And what is `try_set` supposed to do? Shouldn't it take an argument to compare to instead of comparing to itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [C++11 N3337 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) does not require that method for `bool`.

29.5 "Atomic types"

```
template <class T> struct atomic {
  [...]
}

template <> struct atomic<integral> {
  [...]
  integral fetch_or(integral , memory_order = memory_order_seq_cst) noexcept;
  [...]
}
```

29.5/1:

> The semantics of the operations on specializations of atomic are defined in 29.6.

29.6.3/2 "Arithmetic operations on atomic types":

> In the declarations of these functions and function template specializations, the name integral refers to an integral type and the name atomic-integral refers to either atomic or to a named base class for integral from Table 145 or inferred from Table 146.

and Table 145 does not contain `bool`.

So only the integral (without `bool`) specializations of `struct` will have that method.

This is a bit confusing because in the rest of the standard, "integral types" includes bool, 3.9.1/7 "Fundamental types":

> Types bool, char, char16_t, char32_t, wchar_t, and the signed and unsigned integer types are collectively called integral types. A synonym for integral type is integer type.